# Will these enumerate/start to enumerate a Queue?

Tags: c#, multithreading, enumeration

I have a static Queue that can be accessed from different threads.

The Queue has a wrapper implemented which locks properly on add/remove/set.
Also there is a method where I lock and return a copy of the Queue, but this makes a new enumerable, which is a bit of a waste, so I would only want to call it if it is necessary.

I would not want to needlessly copy the queue, but enumerating on it can throw an exception if the queue is changed while I'm enumerating on in.

Is there a chance that these throw an exception while enumerating (because of the reasons above of course):

- `QueueWrapper.InnerQueue.Any()` (empty any)
- `QueueWrapper.InnerQueue.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Something)`
- `QueueWrapper.InnerQueue.Except(element)`

Where should I replace `QueueWrapper.InnerQueue` with `QueueWrapper.GetQueueCopy()`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer the question, but FYI, there is a concurrent queue available in .NET : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/dd267265.aspx

Comment: *C4stor* is right: if you can use a **built-in implementation** could greatly simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

Enumeration only throws when you change the underlying collection. The LINQ operators (`Any`, `FirstOrDefault` and `Except` in your case) do not change the collection, so they won't throw.

Comment: NO :). But if one thread calling `Any`, `First` or `Except`, and an other thread modifies the collection during the execution of the above methods, can they throw the exception?

Comment: Yes, but that isn't something you can prepare for. If you aren't synchronizing (`lock`) this code, and you need it to be thread safe then, yes, immutable collections are the way to go. However, synchronizing the code is where you should start, if it is an option. In that case, the above explanation still stands.

Answer (score 0):

All the operations you show will indeed enumerate the queue so you won't be able to change it during these, so it's not thread-safe (well depends on the way you lock the update operations of your queue).

If you need to protect enumerations then you need a higher level layer of locking.

To be optimal, to avoid locking new readers when there is already a reader you can use a **ReaderWriterLockSlim** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

You would have code like:

```
ReaderWriterLockSlim rwls = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
...
rwls.EnterReadLock();
try
{
    // some enumeration
}
finally
{
    rwls.ExitReadLock();
}
...
rwls.EnterWriteLock();
try
{
    // some bulk update
}
finally
{
    rwls.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

This way you can have **n parallel enumerations** but **only one update** running at any given time.